# determine if $A=\{(x, y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : y \ne x -1\}$ is a Subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

What I have done so far:
$a)$
$y \ne x-1$ for $(x,y)=(0,0)$
$0 ≠ 0-1$
$0 ≠-1$ ?

$b)$
$v_1(x_1,y_1), v_2(a,b)$ then $v_1+v_2$
$x_1+y_1≠ x_1+y_1-1-1$
$x_1+y_1≠(x_1-1)+(y_1-1)$
Closed under addition

$c)$
$a(x_1,y1) = ay_1≠ a(x_1-1)$
Closed under multiplication
What about case $a)$?
I am confused. Is $A$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: what is the meaning of "<>"?

Comment: I am sorry . i just edit <> with ≠

Comment: Not equal isn't a equivalence relation like equal. So your arguments for b and c are wrong. The set is neither closed under addition nor multiplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\vec u=(1,0)\notin A$ but $\vec v=(2,0)\in A$.

If $A$ were a subspace, for any $\vec w\in A$ and any $\lambda\in{\mathbb R}$, $\lambda \vec w\in A$.

But in this case, take $\vec w=\vec v$ and $\lambda=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: In general, a (proper) subspace of ${\mathbb R}^n$ must be defined by, at most, $n-1$ **linear equations of its variables**